# simple recursion acting oppositely

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

so I'm currently working on a method that should print elements in a list in the forward direction but they are printing in the opposite direction.

for example, if my word that's supposed to be printed is p, e, p, p, e, r what's coming out is r, e, p, p, e, p (which is pepper backwards).

here is my code

```
 private void replace(RecursList<E> List, int positionChosen,
     int index){ 

  if(positionChosen >= list.elements.size()+1) return;

  if(index <= this.elements.size()) {

     this.elements.set(positionChosen,  list.elements.get(index)); 
     replace(list,++positionChosen, ++index); 

     return; 
  }
}
```

when I call replace().toString() (I omitted the parameters here) it prints backwards. I know It's not my toString() method because it works for everything else so it must be the structure of my recursive call. any insights as to what might be wrong?

this is my to string method

```
private String toStringHelper(ArrayList<T> elements, int index){
  if(index>=elements.size())return "";

  String s = toStringHelper(elements, index+1);

  if(index < elements.size()-1) s+=", ";

  s+=elements.get(index).toString();

  return s; 
}
```

Comment: There are several parts of your question which could benefit from clarification. *(1)* Your `replace` method refers to *both* instance data (`this.elements`) and data from the local parameter `RecursList` -- why? *(2)* What is `this.elements` (type and what it refers to)? *(3)* What is the relationship between your `toStringHelper` method and the presumably-overloaded `toString` method? How does the latter call the former? *(4)* Specifically how are `replace` and `toString` called (including params)? The call you supply (`replace().toString()`) will not compile, as `replace` returns void.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the `toStringHelper` method.  The lines `String s = toStringHelper(elements, index+1);` followed by `s+=elements.get(index).toString();` are constructing the answer by **appending** the current element **behind** the answer based on all the stuff after it.

Change the concatenation to `s = elements.get(index).toString() + s;`, i.e., prepend rather than append the current element (and comma).